# How to version control & branch a MySQL Database without making full copies of the DB?

Tags: mysql, version-control, relational-database, rdbms

I have a MySQL database that is used by 20+ people with frequent changes. I need it under version control with branching, logs of which users made which changes, and I need to retain the entire history of each branch for up to a year. Spending money on this would also be less than ideal, but manageable.

The database is used to store data that closely relates to code written by a team of programmers who will be working on different features. Each feature has to have its own branch which will be merged into the main branch upon completion of a successful test of the code & data. When a programmer changes their code, they also have to change the database to reflect the change in their code. This could include frequent schema changes. Of course, more than one programmer may work on the same branch at the same time. They also need to roll back changes or merge branches into the main branch at their discretion. The database is used to generate JSON data and other files that a product we develop uses to run. We can't just use one set of tables keyed by each user because each user needs the ability to change the schema without it affecting other users.

I'm particularly worried about the storage space requirements for this. The database currently has 45 tables, each taking about 30mb. If each of the 20 users changes their branch once a day for a year, and if the version control solution requires saving full copies of tables, that's 30mb * 45 tables * 20 branches * 365 days of history = 9855 GB of storage required. I'd rather not have to reserve almost a terabyte of storage for this database.

I'm basically just looking for a version control system that supports schema changes and only keeps one copy of each unique file, like how TimeMachine backups on macOS work. (If you back up with TimeMachine and then just change one file and back up again, it makes a bunch of sym links for the unchanged files and only copies the changes to your backup drive.)

I have a list of version control systems that support MySQL but I'm having trouble finding info on whether or not they make full copies of the database without going through the trouble of actually trying out each one. Here's the list I found:

- Liquibase
- Flyway
- FluentMigrator
- Ruby on Rails Migrations
- DBV
- DBGeni
- Sqitch
- DeltaSQL

Comment: Why do you want to use branches, and what do you actually want to do with the resulting setup? - would you ever need to roll anything back, or do you just need the audit logging you mention? (And why can't you just use one set of tables keyed additionally by user?) I think we need to understand the business requirement before we can advise.

Comment: @MandyShaw I've updated the question to include that info.

Comment: So, just to be clear, we are talking about both schema changes (small storage requirements) and 30MB worth of data per branch, with both needing to be under version control? I'd be inclined to worry about the schema and the data separately, honestly.

Comment: Do you need both database schema and data changes under version control? How are changes in database related to user? If  you have per-user tables - you can just create per-user mysqldump.sql files and let Git do the rest. Also you can add triggers to all tables for all data changing queries. PS: https://sourceforge.net/projects/deltasql/  - one more entry for your list for DB schema version control.

Comment: @MandyShaw Branches would need to include all 45 tables, which are about 30mb each. I would prefer to keep the schema and data together since both could be changed frequently and one is useless without the other.

Comment: I do need the schema under version control because the schema may be changed in each branch. I'm basically just looking for a version control system that only keeps one copy of each unique file but behaves as if it was keeping a full copy of each revision. Like how TimeMachine backups on macOS work, but with version control instead of just backups.

Comment: I get that, but I don't understand why you need to version control the data rather than just back it up - is this all reference data that will be shipped with the product? If this is transaction data re regression testing, is it not the test script/test transactions that need version control, not the data that is the result of that testing?

Comment: @MandyShaw I need version control because multiple developers might be working on different database changes at once. This database is involved with building an application that is required to have build repeatability, so I also need backup. Doesn't version control just mean branching + backups?

Comment: Most applications need build repeatability, I get the version control piece, I just don't get why the data needs it, as opposed to just the schema. I would see a backup as something you do regularly but not in alignment with a development cycle, whereas version control is where you make a change and then commit it, which applies sensibly to a schema, but not to the actual data (except, clearly, for reference data); unless, for example, you are testing in clearly defined cycles and need to commit the whole database after each cycle. I have clearly misunderstood something, so never mind.